# SVN checkout to directory I don't own (via SSH)

Tags: svn, ssh, sudo, private-key

I'm using SVN+SSH to authenticate to my SVN server. I'm trying to checkout a repo on another server. The directory to which I want to checkout is not owned by my, so I wanted to `sudo` it up.

When I try `svn co svn+ssh://me@myserver.com/svn/MyRepo`, naturally, I can't write to the directory and the checkout fails.

When I try `sudo svn co svn+ssh://me@myserver.com/svn/MyRepo`, my SSH key can't seem to be accessed - I get the error: "Permission denied (publickey)"

So I want to have sudo run as myself, yet give me extra privileges (I think). How do I do that? E.g. I need permission to write to the directory but also need to be able to access my SSH key.

Comment: And I know I can change the owner/group of the directory to myself, but that's not what I'm asking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `sudo`, you try to authenticate himself on remote host not as current-local user (obviously) and thus - doesn't provide *needed* public key (ieven if can provide *any*)

I think, you have to re-read SVN Book, "svnserve, a Custom Server" chapter and ["Tunneling over SSH"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth) section most carefully, and create "custom tunnel", in which you (at least) will use your correct, predefined key: `ssh -i ...` in tunnel definition

Comment: Editing `~/.subversion/config`, in the `tunnels` section where the ssh command is located and adding `-i /path/to/my/key` switch seems to work. Thanks!